# Why don't my power or home button on my iPhone 4 work?

Tags: iphone

My home and power button don't work. I also tried the assistive touch, but those buttons don't still work. What should I do?

Comment: So the onscreen menus of assistive touch do not work either?

Answer (score 1):

Assistive touch should work because it is an on-screen feature not hardware. The home button might not be working because of a hardware failure.